# Locker Service/Lightning Out Issue

Tags: lightning-aura-components, locker-service, lightning-out

I have a Managed Package Lightning Component being exposed to a non-Managed Package VF page via Lightning Out. With Locker Service enabled, I get the following errors for managed package static resources being loaded:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load {url}/{namespace}__jquery224. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://{name}--c.na40.visual.force.com' is therefore not allowed access.

I was under the impression that Reference W-3280831 (https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A00000189YMQAY) addresses this, but the org is on Spring 17' and still faces the issue. any ideas?

Comment: Just now checked our component in VF using lightning-out and it works fine.

Comment: Hello Praveen, is the component being referenced part of a managed package that you are accessing outside the package? When the Visualforce page is part of the package it works fine/as expected.

Comment: Yes I'm displaying our managed component in a vf page which is outside of the package via lightning-out